# Required response doesn't display message where input = radio

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a database-driven test and inserted "required" before some closing tags so that users can't submit the results until they've at least attempted to answer all the questions.

Below is the code for two types of questions, where input type = radio or text...

```
$QA = '<div class="Answer">
      <label class="Wide" for="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'"><div    class="Radio"><input type="radio" name="q'.$QID.'[]" id="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'" value="'.$Value.'" style="display: none;" required> '.$Value.'.  '.$QA.'</div></label></div>';
```

Text Input...

```
$QA = '<div class="Answer">
      <label for="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'"><div class="Multiple-Choice"> <input type="text" name="q'.$QID.'[]" id="q'.$QID.'-'.$Value.'" value=""  required></div></label></div>';
```

The text input works fine. If a user clicks the submit button before answering a text question, the page jumps up to the question they didn't answer, and a message pops up: "Please fill out this field."

But if they click the submit button without answering a question where the input type is "radio," nothing happens. The page doesn't submit (like it's supposed to), but the user may not have a clue why because the page doesn't jump up to the unanswered question, and no message is displayed.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

That should not be your only check if a question has been answered.

Before sending the data with jquery you should also loop through all the fields and check if some field has no value and return the user to that field with an error message.

After that you should have a check for every field in your php part as well and return an error to the user when ajax loads.

The users can remove the front-end checks but they can not skip the back-end ones.

Example of query loop and checks

```
var inputs = $('#myForm :input');

inputs.each(function(index, value) {
    if ($(value).val() == '') { //check if the input is empty 
        //return the error
    }
});
```

You get the point. You should have the same type of checks in the php part.

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't working for me. I replaced #myForm with #quiz (my form's ID, then inserted your script near the bottom of the page. But if I click the submit button without answering any questions, it still submits. I don't understand the value "index." Do I need to substitute something for that?

Comment: `$(value)` is your element.